# vue - build project doesn't request main.js

Tags: vue.js

**Version**

2.5.2

**Reproduction link**

http://test.airspace.cn/

**Steps to reproduce**

1.Clear the browser cache

2.Enter url and dev-tool see if there is a blank page phenomenon. lt's because the main.js doesn't request.

3.Refresh the browser, lt's normal.

4.Open a new browser tab and enter the url, blank page will appear occasionally.

**What is expected?**

can reach the site everytime

**What is actually happening?**

blank page

open a new tab and enter a url

[image: open a new tab and enter a url]

refresh again and again

[image: refresh again and again]

this is main.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import ElementUI from 'element-ui'
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css'
import '@/config/base'
import * as allFilters from '@/config/filter'
import { category } from '@/config/constant'
import App from '@/App'
import router from '@/router'
import store from '@/store/index'
import '@/directive'


Vue.config.productionTip = false

// Vue.use(Button)
Vue.use(Vuex)
Vue.use(ElementUI, { size: 'small' })

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
})

Object.keys(allFilters).forEach((key) => {
  Vue.filter(key, allFilters[key])
})

store.dispatch('dispatchPlaneTypes')
store.dispatch('dispatchPlaneBrands')

process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? console.log(category) : '' //eslint-disable-line
```

Comment: How are you building the app? Is it generated from `vue-cli`? If so, what template did you use?

Comment: Yes, i use vue-cli and build with `vue init webpack`

Comment: There is no `main.js` after compilation from `node build/build.js` as it builds into `app.{hash}.js`

Comment: Yes,  I find this . But where is the problem?